# Android Studio Debugging Error (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

I have this issue with Android Studio for Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Whenever I click the "Run" button to Compile/Debug, it gives me the following error, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Execution failed for task ':HellowWorld:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/kirko/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/dx --dex --output /home/kirko/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld/HellowWorld/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.1-bd6acdb08a01a4b5fc925efd5325b3afe393d991.jar /home/kirko/android-studio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/19.0.1/support-v4-19.0.1.jar
  Error Code:
    127
  Output:
    /home/kirko/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/dx: line 89: exec: java: not found
```

Comment: Could you please post the java code to? because the problem is either in your java code, or you haven't installed Java, Android studio, or its dependencies correctly.

Comment: @MaxLangerak Thanks for assisting. How do I view my java code?

Comment: If you haven't got any code? what are you exactly compiling, android uses xml for markup and Java to run.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set JDK_PATH and PATH in **/etc/profile** file.

```
JDK_PATH=/path/to/jdk/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JDK_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It was fixed by running android studio in admin mode:

```
you@yourComputer:/some/path/to/android-studio/bin$ sudo studio.sh
```

I, sadly, have no idea why this error happens or why this fixes it, but in case you only want to play with android studio, this should unblock you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's a bit late, but I just experienced the same problem. Basically it can't run the last line of the code caused by undefined JAVA_HOME.

Here is the solution :

Open `nano /home/kirko/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/dx`

Go to the last line, you'll find `exec java $javaOpts -jar "$jarpath" "$@"`

Add these two lines before the last line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then your code should be like this

```
..
export JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jdk1.8.0_25
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
exec java $javaOpts -jar "$jarpath" "$@"
```